# Peticion Ajax no reconoce variables de sesion

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estimados tengo el siguiente inconveniente, eh creado 2 VirtualHost con Wampserver, uno llamado ecuservicechile.lc y el otro que representa un subdominio portal.ecuservicechile.lc.

Ambos funcionan bien, excepto las peticiones Ajax que conllevan sesiones de por medio, ya que aquellas peticiones que no incluyen sesiones en el script PHP, las retorna correctamente.

Es como si la peticion Ajax no reconociera las variables de sesion, lo explico un poco

En el siguiente archivo llamado creditos_disponibles.php, si ingreso directo a la URL donde se encuentra que sería ecuservicechile.lc/logica/créditos/créditos_disponibles.php si me retorna los valores correspondientes, pero si hago la llamada a dicha función mediante Ajax desde portal.ecuservicechile.lc/recursos/footer.php no me retorna nada.

Las sessiones se estan propagando correctamente entre ambos sitios, ya que si hago un

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Obtengo los mismos valores de sesion en ambos sitios, pero desconozoco porque la peticion ajax no me reconoce las variables.

Archivo créditos_disponibles.php RUTA ecuservicechile.lc/logica/créditos/créditos_disponibles.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include dirname(__FILE__).'/../../logica/conexion/conexion.php';
class CreditosDisponibles {
    public function Creditos(){
        $con = new Conexion();
 
        if(isset($_SESSION['idusuario'])){
            $datos = $con->obtenerdatos("creditos","usuarios","idusuario = ?",array($_SESSION['idusuario']));
            $creditos = $datos[0]['creditos'];
        }
        return $creditos;
    }
 
 
}
$creditos = new CreditosDisponibles();
if(isset($_POST["action"])){
    $html1 = $creditos->Creditos();
    $data = array(
        "html1" => $html1
    );
    echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

Archivo footer.php dentro de portal.ecuservicechile.lc/recursos/footer.php

```
function creditos(){
        var action = 'fetch_data';
        $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo $dominioRaiz;?>logica/creditos/creditos_disponibles.php",
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data:{ action:action},
            success:function(data){
                $('#creditos').html(data.html1);
 
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Probablemente el cliente no está compartiendo la cookie de la sesión entre el dominio y el sub-dominio debido a como se registra la misma. ¿Cuáles son los valores de tu configuración de la cookie de sesión?

Comment: Pero si no las compartiera como dices tu, porque si yo en alguna pagina del dominio hago un var_dump($_SESSION), obtengo los mismos valores que si hago var_dump en el subdominio, es decir que las sesiones si se propagan entre ambos, pero en las peticiones ajax no me las reconoce, por el momento solo hago un session_start y asignó las variables, no las tengo configuradas

Comment: si haces un `var_dump()` en ambos e imprime lo mismo, ¿por qué dices que _no reconoce las variables_? Evidentemente, el `var_dup()` demuestra que SI las reconoce.

Comment: Si las reconoce, pero cuando trato de llamar los datos vía ajax ahí no me las reconoce, es como si no existieran, como menciono en la pregunta si hago una petición ajax desde el subdominio al dominio,si el script php conlleva un SESSION no me muestra nada, pero si me voy directo al script php en el dominio y ejecutó ese script, funciona correctamente

Comment: ¿Si haces la misma petición via ajax desde el dominio al dominio (sin cruzar) funciona bien?

Comment: Exacto, si hago esa petición sin hacer el cruce funciona bien y me retorna los datos correspondientews, pero al hacerl la petición cruzada no me retorna nada, no reconoce las sesiones a pesar de que si se están propagando entre dominio y subdominio, nose si deba poner alguna regla en htaccess o algo por el estilo

Comment: Qué te devuelve si haces el `var_dump($_SESSION);` en la llamada ajax y pones ese texto en algún lugar de la página para que sea visible.

Comment: Si hago la lamada de la funcion ajax dentro del mismo dominio recibo array(8) { ["fecha"]=> string(18) "2021-05-04 3:45:43" ["correo"]=> string(30) "correo@dominio" ["nombre"]=> string(8) "PEPITO" ["apellido"]=> string(7) "ROSAS" ["idusuario"]=> string(9) "USERCOD" ["sesion-start"]=> int(1620114343) ["sesion-expire"]=> int(1620115441) ["sid"]=> string(26) "qf4kasdni23g6esgnsr7bff0i5" } , pero si se hace la llamada ajax desde el subdominio el array lo devuelve vacio.

Comment: @JonathanAlarcon tenes que asegurarte que la cookie que se crea en el dominio principal se cree para el [dominio completo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvW3C.png). Proba establecer [`session.cookie_domain`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain) (`ej: ini_set('session.cookie_domain', [DOMINIO];`) antes de `session_start`

Comment: eh puesto las lineas de codigo que me mencionas y sigue sin retornar nada, es raro que si ejecuto el script desde ecuservicechile.lc se muestre todo bien, pero si lo ejecuto en portal.ecuservicechile.lc no muestre nada, a pesar de que si existen las variables de session

Comment: @JonathanAlarcon, es lógico que sea así ya que para el navegador son distintos dominios. ¿Verificaste como se crea la cookie? ¿Probaste enviar la cookie en la llamada ajax?

Comment: por ahora creo las sesiones asi, session_start(); $_SESSION['nombre] = $valor; entonces el navegador interpreta que son dominios diferentes, pero porque razon si me comparte las sesiones entre domonio y subdominio, pero con ajax no lo hace ? tendre que especificar algo mas en mi htacces o no ??